# Ruby/rails array fill in empty items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Imagine I have an array like:

```
[["abc","zxy","fgh"], ["fgj","xxy"], ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
```

I want to have an array that would contain all the elements for each subarray, plus appended empty (or default) items until the length of the largest subarray.

For the example, this would be:

```
[["abc","zxy","fgh", ""], ["fgj","xxy", "", ""], ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
array=[["abc","zxy","fgh"], ["fgj","xxy"], ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
array.map {|sub_array| sub_array.in_groups_of(4, "").flatten }

#=> [["abc", "zxy", "fgh", ""],
#    ["fgj", "xxy", "", ""],
#    ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
```

Comment: For future visitors, note that `in_groups_of` is not in Ruby Core  and requires ActiveSupport.

Comment: True. But the question is tagged with ruby-on-rails as well.

Comment: yes, I actually asked because I knew of in_groups_of but was at a loss at how to use it effectively.

Answer (score 5):

Map each array to a new array with an initial size of the max of all the arrays, falling back to a default value when there is no value.

```
array = [["abc","zxy","fgh"], ["fgj","xxy"], ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
max_size = array.map(&:size).max
array.map { |a| Array.new(max_size) { |i| a[i] || '' } }
#=> [["abc", "zxy", "fgh", ""],
#    ["fgj", "xxy", "", ""],
#    ["eee", "aaa", "bbb", "hhh"]]
```

Note that if your initial (sub)arrays have a `nil` in them, this will replace it with an empty string `''`.